# Arquivo de recurso duplicado

Tags: delphi

Estou com um projeto que tem as seguintes diretivas de arquivos de recursos:

```
{$R *.DFM}
{$R UAC.res}
```

Depois que eu copiei uma parte do projeto para outra pasta, me apresenta o seguinte erro após compilar:

> "[DCC Error] E2161 Warning: Duplicate resource:  Type 24
>   (user-defined), ID 1; File D:\Projeto\EmailRB\EMAILRB.res resource
>   kept; file UAC.res resource discarded."

`EMAILRB.res` é criado ao compilar o projeto e `UAC.res`, foi um arquivo que criei para contornar uma limitação do UAC do Windows.

Como faço para resolver este problema?

Comment: Provável que em algum lugar do projeto esteja declarado a diretiva de `{$R *.res}` então ele estaria lhe informando que a `UAC.res` esta duplicada.

Answer (score 2):

Va ao source do projeto, (menu Project-> View Source) e verifique se a diretiva `{$R *.res}` não foi definida.

Se estiver definida todos os arquivos `.res` será adicionado automaticamente, sem a necessidade de declarar em outras partes.

Ao compilar a unit do projeto vai anexar todos os `.res` e ao compilar as units ele esta anexando as declaradas, ou seja, existe sim a duplicidade!

Basta remover a `UAC.res` da declaração.

Comment: Obrigado Júnior pelo retorno. Vou verificar aqui e retorno o resultado.

Comment: Resolvido. Apaguei o arquivo "EMAILRB.res" e, ao recompilar, o Delphi o recriou e não deu mais o erro de duplicidade. Agradeço a todos que ajudaram.